# Mounted ExFat Disk: No such file or directory

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

I'm using an ExFat external disk on Ubuntu 18.04.4 with auto-mount but after a while I can't copy or edit items on the disk anymore but the items are still accessible.

After a system-restart I can write to the drive again.

**Followed steps:**

1 - sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
2 - sudo mkdir /home/user-folder/NETWORK-HDD
3 - Edit sudo nano /etc/fstab
4 - Add line: UUID=****-**** /home/user-folder/NETWORK-HDD auto defaults 0 0
5 - sudo mount -a

> *Be advised that I'm not an expert in Linux, just started using it.*

Comment: Are you seeing an error message when you try to edit / copy files to the disk? Check that you are the owner of those files (right click and see properties, or chown in terminal)

Comment: Yes, shows me the following error: No such file or directory and yes I'm the owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the culprit. Filenames with a colon are the issue.

Whenever I tried to copy a file with a colon in the name to or from the mounted disk it failed. Removing the colons fixed the issue.